# Focused element from javascript can't enter group in voiceover until unfocusing group and then navigating back to group with voiceover keys

Tags: javascript, html, macos, accessibility, voiceover

I have a top level element that has role="navigation" and an aria-label. When the page is loaded, this element is focused in JavaScript, and voiceover correctly reads its aria-label. However, if I do voiceover (control + option) + shift + down, I can't enter the elements children. But if I focus on another element, and then use voiceover to navigate back to the same element, then doing control + option + shift + down correctly enters the group and can find the elements children through voiceoverkeys. In all cases, I can enter the group using voiceover(control + option) + right key, but i'm basically wondering why focusing an element changes the ability of the voiceover keys to enter the group.

I.e.

```
<div role="navigation" aria-label="some-label">
   <some-stuff/>
   ...
</div>
```

Comment: try adding a `tabindex="0"`, I think the behaviour is because you are forcing focus onto the element (which is not focusable) and that is confusing the accessibility tree.

Comment: Thank you! Pretty sure that's the issue.